# Scalar Triple/Box Product

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

Consider a tetrahedron which has two vectors **a** and **b** forming its base and a third vector **c**. Now  the volume of a tetrahedron is given by one third of the base multiplied by the height. The area of the base is found by taking half the cross product of **a** and **b** and is easily understood. Now the part that confuses me; the perpendicular height of the tetrahedron is said to be the projection of the vector **c** in the direction of vector **n** which is equivalent to $\mathbf{a}\times \mathbf{b}$. This must mean therefore that since the magnitude of the projection (height) is $|\mathbf{c}|\cos(\theta)$[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45p9k.png), by the use of the dot product we should be able to conclude that the height is $\mathbf{c}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{n}}$ and finally the volume should be given by $1/3(|1/2(\mathbf{a}\times \mathbf{b})|)\mathbf{c}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{n}}$. However, my textbook arrives at the conclusion of $1/6|(\mathbf{a}\times \mathbf{b})\cdot\mathbf{c}|$ which befuddles me. Attached is the image of the tetrahedron in question. [image: 1]

Comment: I don't know what you mean by c.n-hat. Your post would be easier to read, if you would take some time to learn about formatting mathematics on this website. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I apologize. I will learn how do that for future posts. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the same expression. Notice that $$a\times b=|a\times b|\hat n$$
where $\hat n$ is the unit vector perpendicular to the $ab$ plane. Then $$||a\times b|(\hat n\cdot c)|=|(a\times b)\cdot c|$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I get it now.